# Kotlin generateSequence do not remember internal state

Tags: kotlin, jvm

So I'm learning Kotlin and I have a question about `generateSequence`

```java
val numberGenerator: Sequence<Int> = generateSequence(0) { it + 1 }
println(numberGenerator.take(10).toList())
println(numberGenerator.take(3).toList())
```

Code above generated this results:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2]
```

I would like to achive sth like that:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[10, 11, 12]
```

I would like this generator to remember internal state about last element and continue from that, is there built in solution for that in Kotlin?

Comment: you get your answer?

Comment: so you need `drop(10)` not `take` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your need, but I think it is a misfit for the intent of a Sequence. It is meant to be a definition of an infinite stream that can be used multiple times to generate the same stream.

I think you will have to do a little bit of your own wrapping and adapting if you want to produce some set of slices of values. Here are some options:

```
fun main() {
    val myList = generateSequence(0) { it + 1 }.take(10).toList()
    val myList2 = generateSequence(10) { it + 1 }.take(3).toList()
    println(myList)
    println(myList2)

    val myListV2 = List(10) { index -> index }
    val myListV2_2 = List(3) { index -> 10 + index }
    println(myListV2)
    println(myListV2_2)

    val myListV3 = (0..9).toList()
    val myListV3_2 = (10..12).toList()
    println(myListV3)
    println(myListV3_2)
}
```

Comment: I would also add @`Andrew Churilo` answer which provides an example of using `subList`

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't save state of `Sequence`. But you can take all items and split them to separate lists.

```
val numberGenerator: Sequence<Int> = generateSequence(0) { it + 1 }
val fullList = numberGenerator.take(13).toList()
val part1 = fullList.subList(0, 10)
val part2 = fullList.subList(10, 13)
println(part1)
println(part2)
```